# How where method works in Laravel Models?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

We frequently use `where` method with our models but it's not defined in Base Model class so how laravel is doing this magic?

e.g `MyModel::where('id, 2)->get();`

The above where will definitely fetch the record having id equals 2 but where & how is this happening! I traced back to the Base Model in Laravel but didn't found where method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this magic resides behind a Facade Pattern https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm

But in Laravel case, they use Static methods in their Facades (`\Illuminate\Support\Facades` namespace), and create instance automatically to call those methods from instance, so you don't have to instantiate the Class yourself to start using the methods. For example when you use `DB::`, `Cache::`, `Str::` to call static method.

However for Eloquent, Laravel uses this approach more internally without exposing the Model to `\Illuminate\Support\Facades` namespace, by configuring Eloquent Model to instantiate automatically the Model and creates`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` Eloquent Builder and forward those static methods call to the Eloquent Builder instance or to Query Builder one.

A model extends `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` which has a special way to call any method statically at runtime.

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic static method calls into the method.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

So at a certain point, the Builder classes an Eloquent use a Trait

```
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls;
```

to forward call to each others so that a Model can forward its static method to method from the created instance of Eloquent builder. So if model does not have `where` method, it will forward it to the where method of the newly created nstance of Eloquent Builder.

From a look of Facade Pattern, here is how Laravel calls a method from an instance but in a static way :

```
// \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
/**
 * Handle dynamic, static calls to the object.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $args
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    if (! $instance) {
        throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
    }

    return $instance->$method(...$args);
}
```

So calling `User::where()` creates an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and forward method call to that instance, here is the method :

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php
/**
 * Add a basic where clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string|array|\Closure  $column
 * @param  mixed   $operator
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @return $this
 */
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    if ($column instanceof Closure) {
        $column($query = $this->model->newModelQuery());

        $this->query->addNestedWhereQuery($query->getQuery(), $boolean);
    } else {
        $this->query->where(...func_get_args());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: So it means if I call `MyModel::test()`  it will go to `__callStatic` method right?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin you can try to `echo $method` in the `__callStatic()` and you'll see it

Answer (score 2):

You can find the method [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L223) . `framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php`

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
    {
        if ($column instanceof Closure) {
            $column($query = $this->model->newModelQuery());
            $this->query->addNestedWhereQuery($query->getQuery(), $boolean);
        } else {
            $this->query->where(...func_get_args());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

[Some more info about it](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where)

Comment: the link you share is about Builder Class. I'm talking about Base Model Class i.e when I extend a class from Model e.g MyClass extends Model

Comment: In this case, take a look in here: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html . the ```newCollection``` method wich returns a collection instance (wich have the where method)

Comment: So `newCollection` allow us to use where method? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I think so, I searched a lot in the documentation and that's what I found. sorry for not having a precise answer. You can take a look at the collection class here: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_where . So in your model class you can a call a method (newCollection) wich returns a collection that allows you to use the where method you're looking for. I think that's it